# Bash Script Efficient For Loop (Different Source File)

Tags: linux, bash, file, for-loop

First of all i'm a beginner in bash scripting. I usually code in Java but this certain task requires me to create some bash scripts in Linux. FYI i've already made a working script but I think its not efficient enough because of the large files I'm dealing with.

The problem is simple I have 2 logs that I need to compare and make some correction on one of the logs... ill call it logA and logB. This 2 logs contains different format here is an example:

> 01/04/2015 **06:48:59**|9691427842139609|601113090635|PR|30.00|8.3|1.7| <- log A
>
> 17978712 2015-04-01 **06:48:44** 601113090635   SUCCESS DealerERecharge.<-log B
>
> **17978714** 2015-04-01 **06:48:49** 601113090635   SUCCESS DealerERecharge.<-log B

As you can see there is a gap in time stamp. The actual logs that will match with log A is the one with the ID 17978714 because it is the closest time from it. The highest time gap I've seen is 1 minute. I cant use the RANGE logic because if there are more than one line on log B that is within the 1 minute range then all of the line will show in my regenerated log.

The script I made contains a for loop which iterate the timestamp of log A until it hits something in log B (The first one it hits is the closest)

Inside the for loop I have this line of code which makes the loop slow.

```
 LINEOUTPUT=$(less $File2 | grep "Validation 1" | grep "Validation 2" | grep "Timestamp From Log A")
```

I've read some sample using SED but the problem is I have 2 more validation to consider before matching it with the time stamp.

The validation works as a filter to narrow down the exact match for log A and B.

**Additional Info:** I tried doing some benchmark test for the script I made by performing some loop. One thing I've noticed is that even though I only use 1 pipe for that script the loop tick is still slow.

Comment: are both logs in sort order wrt the timestamp ?

Comment: @amdixon - Yes. But log B is much bigger because it contains more logs which you cant find in log A. Think of log B as the Master File

Comment: think you can do this in two passes : one use awk or equivalent to reformat the timestamps to the same form ( do this on the smaller file ), two use sort with -m flag to merge based on the timestamp key

Comment: @amdixon - Well I cant merge both logs... I only need to correct some data from log A by using data from log B.

Comment: @amdixon - I've also made some experiment by narrowing it down into 1 pipe... but you can still notice the slow ticks per loop.